Different meanings of "would"

I will help her when she comes in

I would help her when she came in


I think 1 means it is my plan to do something once she enteres and it probably is a one time action. On the other hand "would" in 2 means the same as "used to". I think adding something like "I thought I would help her when she came in" makes it sound like a single action but without that it is the same as "used to". What is your opinion?

No 'opinion' about it - would in sentence 2 definitely implies a habitual action in the past.

(1)

I will help her when she comes in.

Agree that this is probably a one-time action.
(2)

I would help her when she came in.

This is not the conditional use of would. This has to be a repeated action that took place in the past For example:

Every Tuesday, I would help her when she came in.

If you exchange if for when, then it can be either repeated or conditional:

I would help her if she came in.

